# FullCalendar.js show title tags when hovering an event?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I was looking in the documentation and didn't see anything regarding display of a title tag when hovering an event displayed on a calendar event using the fullcalendar.js scripts. Maybe that's not covered int he documentation because it's a standard function but I'm not seeing any tricks on implementing that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the fancy jQuery-UI toolips on your events, try doing this.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element
            .attr('title', 'foo')
            .tooltip();
    },
...
});
```

Comment: Will do and will report back. Can't do it right now being pulled into something but within the next few days I'll give it a test and hope for the best.

Comment: finally came back to review this and no idea where that script gets placed. (<n00bAlert) I tried just following the call to the eventSources as well as afterwards where it sets the Title, StartTime and URL but either way I'm breaking the actual calendar. Has this been tested? My guess is I'm testing the wrong location.

Comment: It gets placed in your `{}` option object when you call `.fullcalendar`

Comment: Amph, works great (as a next step) so now each item has "foo" appearing as a tooltip (top centered). Next I need to get the tooltips to expose information (variables) not yet loaded when that runs. My database is running two hybrid FOR loops and the tip will need to display unique data on each tip. PS, I tried to give the +1 but stack won't let me cuz I'm a n00b. (in this forum at least) I'll see if I can add that but if you have a suggestion or want to see usage (code) let me know and thanks.